# How to get the bold tag <b> in a string to take effect when displayed on screen?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have an MVC application wherein I have a string that gets created dynamically from the view model using C# code, there are certain words that need to be marked in bold. For instance, if the string created from C# code is 'This is a test', I wish to display the word 'test' as bold when it is passed from the view model to the cshtml view and is displayed on screen, I tried Regex.replace, which helped me get the text wrapped in bold tags, but after that what I saw on screen was plain text with tags 'This is a < b >test< /b >, while I expected it to be - 'This is a **test**'. I tried Regex.replace, but that didn't work. Can someone please suggest what should be done in this case ? Below is my code:

```
content = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(content, wordToHighlight, "<b>" + wordToHighlight + "</b>", System.Text.RegularExpressions.RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

Comment: Check this out and let me know if it suffices to your need: https://dotnetfiddle.net/AXQb3d

Comment: @RahulSharma, this is displaying the text with tags like <b>test</b>, but my requirement is that I need to display the text in bold.

Comment: In your View,use: `@Html.Raw(content)` to display your string.

Comment: @RahulSharma, thanks, this worked

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your case:

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
    String term = "test";
    String input = "This is a test";
    String result = Regex.Replace( input, String.Join("|", term.Split(' ')), @"<b>$&</b>");
    Console.Out.WriteLine(result);
    }
}
```

would give you: `This is a <b>test</b>`

In order to display this string in your View, use:

```
@Html.Raw(result)
```

which will display your string as: This is a **test**